# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. response had HTTP status code 401

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am developing a cordova App and I am having issue with this code.
I am trying to make a cross domain access to web service.

Using chrome and firefox, I receive a 401 unauthorized error.
In IE it works fine and gives back the response that I expect.

The scenario here is that in IE it is asking for server side login details. If I give those details it'll work fine, otherwise it'll give a 401 error as it does all of the time in the other two browsers.

Can anyone help me with this?  How can I send the server's login details along with the user entered login details?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('form#loginForm').submit(function() { // loginForm is submitted
    var username = $('#username').val(); // get username
    var password = $('#password').val(); // get password
    alert(username);
    var UserData= {"userName":username , "password":password};
    var jsonString=JSON.stringify(UserData);
    var datanew  = "loginemployee="+ jsonString;
     if (UserData) { // values are not empty
                $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://", // URL 

            // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            // If reply is json means uncomment the below line.
             dataType: "json",
            // send username and password as parameters 
            data: datanew,    // script call was *not* successful
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('div#loginResult').text("responseText: " +XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ", textStatus: " + textStatus + ", `enter code here`errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
            }, // error 
            // script call was successful 
            // data contains the JSON values returned by the Perl script 
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
                if (data.error) { // script returned error
                    $('div#loginResult').text("data.error: " + data.error);
                    $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
                } // if
                else { // login was successful
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    window.location="TL_HOME.html";
                } //else
            } // success
        }); // ajax/ if
    } // if
    else {
        $('div#loginResult').text("enter username and password");
        $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
    } // else
    $('div#loginResult').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: you have to enable CORS on both client and server.

Comment: but its actually a third party server where i cant modify, is ter any other way..!

Comment: Also its working fine in IE 8 ..! WITHOUT MODIFYING SERVER SIDE..!

Comment: add this in your config.xml `<access origin="*" />`